# Laravel 5.1 swith language

Tags: php, laravel

I try to make language swith at Laravel 5.1.

At my **config/languages.php** i use:

```
<?php

return [
    'en' => 'en',
    'ru' => 'ru',
];
```

At my **LanguageController** i use:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Config;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class LanguageController extends Controller {

    public function switchLang($lang)
        {
        if (array_key_exists($lang, Config::get('languages'))) {
            Session::set('applocale', $lang);
        }
        return Redirect::back();
        }
}
```

At the **layout.blade** i write:

```
const LANG = '{{ Config::get('languages')[App::getLocale()] }}';
```

At **app/Http/Kernel** i add at 22 line:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,
```

And at the routes i use:

```
Route::get('lang/{lang}', ['as'=>'lang.switch', 'uses'=>'LanguageController@switchLang']);
```

But when i try go to site.com/lang/en i received error:

```
ErrorException in LanguageController.php line 16:
array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
```

Who can say me, where my mistake? If you need more details - please, ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try clear config cache

```sh
php artisan config:cache
```